# Bootstrap navbar styling issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a rather minor issue, but enough to drive me up a wall. Sometimes I swear I have OCD, though not diagnosed.

What's going on is that I'm working on a company Web site (starting my own company). I am using the navbar-default, and customizing it to suit the color scheme I want.

One issue, though (see linked pic below):

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK9aV.jpg)

This is the right-most point on my navbar. You can clearly see that there's about a 15px space at the end there that is not the same color as the rest of the navbar. It is a light grey (from the default Bootstrap styling) rather than the white (my customizations). I'm currently using an inline CSS style to try and figure out which class is causing this, but can't seem to do so.

Please help?

Code of navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#s2s-navigation">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="img/s2s-logo-brand.png" /></a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="s2s-navigation">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a id="home" href="pages/home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a id="about" href="pages/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a id="programs" href="pages/programs">Programs</a></li>
    <li><a id="contact" href="pages/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a id="help" href="pages/help">Help</a></li>
    <li><a id="legal" href="pages/legal">Legal</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS (as appropriate to the situation):

```
#s2s-navigation { background: #FFFFFF; }
a#home, a#about, a#programs, a#contact, a#help, a#legal { color: #3BBEFF; }
```

(Yes, I realize I could have wrote that a bit better.)

Comment: You need to post your code as well so that we can help.

Comment: Edited to add the code. Sorry about that.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/yp3LbzgKWZ I can't see the space you mentioned. Your custom CSS?

Comment: Here, you can just go ahead and pull the whole site if you want. That may perhaps be a little easier.

[link](http://stem2success.com/wat-index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.container-fluid` Has a default padding of `15px` 
This is wrapped around your styled navigation. Style a higher level container such as `.navbar-default'

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! You are a LIFE SAVER!!! I had to go look into the uncompressed bootstrap.css file to see the declaration, added an ID of something random for an inline style (to test it), then set the padding-right attribute to 0. Fixed my problem! :D

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting `#s2s-navigation` which is incorrect because it is wrapped inside a container which has a `padding: 0 15px;` So the `background-color` is missed out for the last 15px.

Simple fix is to change

```
#s2s-navigation { background: #FFFFFF; }
```

to

```
.navbar { background: #FFFFFF; }
```